# What are typical runtimes for Miller-Rabin primality testing?

Tags: primes

I'm well aware that a single Miller-Rabin test runs in cubic log time. I know about Montgomery modular exponentiation and GNFS and I'm not asking about any of that fancy theory. What I am wondering is what some representative runtimes for MR (note that this is not the same as an RSA operation) on characteristic hardware (e.g., a 2.2 GHz Opteron or such-and-such graphics card or FPGA).

Comment: Do you have a suitable MR implementation?  Did you run it on your  GHz Opteron or such-and-such?  What did you see?  What definition of "representative" did you use when running?

Comment: What I'm trying to get is a broader sense than if I simply installed PGP or some such and tapped away at keys to generate randomness. I'm not a C coder, so I wouldn't trust my ability to properly benchmark something this complex. A 2.2 GHz Opteron is useful as a benchmark in cryptanalysis but not something I have easy access to (of course I can approximately rescale things to most processors).

Answer (score 3):

One random-base Miller-Rabin test implemented in GMP, average of multiple primes and multiple runs.  i4770K @ 4.3GHz, GMP 6.0.0a.  For numbers under 64-bit, times can be faster using a non-GMP implementation (with x86_64 asm mulmod).  This implementation seems to follow most other C+GMP implementations fairly closely in performance (for the same numbers, [mpz_aprcl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpzaprcl/)'s mpz_sprp runs within a couple percent of the times below).  Using non-standard API calls to do Montgomery math may be faster (and maybe not).

- 20 digits:  1.1 uS
- 40 digits:  3.4 uS
- 80 digits: 14 uS
- 200 digits:  0.11 mS
- 400 digits:  0.65 mS
- 800 digits:  4.7 mS
- 1200 digits:  15 mS
- 1600 digits:  31 mS
- 2000 digits:  53 mS
- 4000 digits:  310 mS

With a good implementation, BPSW (base 2 M-R + [extra] strong Lucas test) takes ~3x the cost of one M-R test.  Lucas test implementations differ a lot more in performance.  A Frobenius test is on the order of 2.5x the cost of a single M-R test.

Answer (score 2):

One round of the Miller-Rabin test might take about 1 millisecond; here is an interactive implementation in JavaScript which you can run in your browser and check the timing yourself:
http://www.javascripter.net/math/primes/millerrabinprimalitytest.htm